# como separar numero php?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Estoy haciendo un contador de regsistro
tengo el siguiente resultado :
codigo:

```
<div class="main-number-inscritos">
   <span class="number-inscritos">{{count}}</span>            
 </div>
```

**Resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero hacer que cada 9> cree un nuevo span y me genere  esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y edita tu aporte para indicar que llevas avanzado y donde ocupas ayuda

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, ¿qué significa querer *hacer que cada 9> cree un nuevo span y me genere esto...*? ¿Qué código has intentado? ¿Cuál es el error o problema? ¿Qué resultado no deseado obtienes?

Answer (score -1):

Podrías probar algo así:

```
<?php
$count = 25;
// crea un array de números
$numeros = str_split($count);

// si el array de los números es < 5 agrega un 0 delante
while(count($numeros) < 5){
    array_unshift($numeros,0);
};

//print_r ($numeros);

// declara una nueva variable, una cadena de texto vaía
$html = "";
// para cada elemento del array de los números crea un elemento span
foreach ($numeros as $val) {
    $html .= '<span>'.$val.'</span>';
}

echo $html;
```